# Unnesting event parameters in JSON format within a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like the one below.  It is relational, but has a dimension called `event_params` which is a JSON object of data related to the `event_name` in the respective row.

```
import pandas as pd

a_df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'date_time': ['2021-01-03 15:12:42', '2021-01-03 15:12:46', '2021-01-03 15:13:01'
                  , '2021-01-03 15:13:12', '2021-01-03 15:13:13', '2021-01-03 15:13:15'
                  , '2021-01-04 03:29:01', '2021-01-04 18:15:14', '2021-01-04 18:16:01'],
    'user_id': ['dhj13h', 'dhj13h', 'dhj13h', 'dhj13h', 'dhj13h', 'dhj13h', '38nr10', '38nr10', '38nr10'],
    'account_id': ['181d9k', '181d9k', '181d9k', '181d9k', '181d9k', '181d9k', '56sf15', '56sf15', '56sf15'],
    'event_name': ['button_click', 'screen_view', 'close_view', 'button_click', 'exit_app', 'uninstall_app'
                   , 'install_app', 'exit_app', 'uninstall_app'],
    'event_params': ['{\'button_id\': \'shop_screen\', \'button_container\': \'main_screen\', \'button_label_text\': \'Enter Shop\'}',
                     '{\'screen_id\': \'shop_main_page\', \'screen_controller\': \'main_view_controller\', \'screen_title\': \'Main Menu\'}',
                     '{\'screen_id\': \'shop_main_page\'}',
                     '{\'button_id\': \'back_to_main_menu\', \'button_container\': \'shop_screen\', \'button_label_text\': \'Exit Shop\'}',
                     '{}',
                     '{}',
                     '{\'utm_campaign\': \'null\', \'utm_source\': \'null\'}',
                     '{}',
                     '{}']
    })
```

**I am looking for approaches on how to handle this sort of data.  My initial approach is with pandas, but I'm open to other methods.**

My ideal end state would be to examine each relationships with respect to each user.  In the current form, I have to compare the dicts/JSON blobs sitting in `event_params` to determine the context behind an event.

I've tried using `explode()` to expand out the `event_params` column.  My thinking is the best sort of approach would be to turn `event_params` into a relational format, where each parameter is an extra row of the dataframe with respect to it's preceding values (in other words, while maintaining the `date_time`, `user_id` and `event_name` that it was related too initially).

My explode approach didn't work well,

```
a_df['event_params'] = a_df['event_params'].apply(eval)
exploded_df = a_df.explode('event_params')
```

The output of that was:

```
date_time, user_id, account_id, event_name, event_params
2021-01-03 15:12:42,dhj13h,181d9k,button_click,button_id
2021-01-03 15:12:42,dhj13h,181d9k,button_click,button_container
```

It has kind of worked, but it stripped the value fields.  Ideally I'd like to maintain those value fields as well.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do exactly. "I am looking for approaches on how to handle this sort of data" / "My ideal end state would be to examine each relationships with respect to each user." --> I don't understand what your target is. If you could define what you want to do more precisely, you're more likely to get help

Comment: I have nested key-value parameter data.  My only idea to explore that data is to explode it to make it relational.  I am looking for other approaches on how I could examine this sort of data structure.  My question is exploratory in nature.  In my view, I can't define what exactly I'm looking for more than that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can transform the `event_params` column from dict to list of dicts, explode it and transform to new columns `key`/`value`:

```py
from ast import literal_eval


a_df = a_df.assign(
    event_params=a_df["event_params"].apply(
        lambda x: [{"key": k, "value": v} for k, v in literal_eval(x).items()]
    )
).explode("event_params")

a_df = pd.concat(
    [a_df, a_df.pop("event_params").apply(pd.Series)],
    axis=1,
).drop(columns=0)

print(a_df)
```

Prints:

```
             date_time user_id account_id     event_name                key                 value
0  2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click          button_id           shop_screen
0  2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click   button_container           main_screen
0  2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click  button_label_text            Enter Shop
1  2021-01-03 15:12:46  dhj13h     181d9k    screen_view          screen_id        shop_main_page
1  2021-01-03 15:12:46  dhj13h     181d9k    screen_view  screen_controller  main_view_controller
1  2021-01-03 15:12:46  dhj13h     181d9k    screen_view       screen_title             Main Menu
2  2021-01-03 15:13:01  dhj13h     181d9k     close_view          screen_id        shop_main_page
3  2021-01-03 15:13:12  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click          button_id     back_to_main_menu
3  2021-01-03 15:13:12  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click   button_container           shop_screen
3  2021-01-03 15:13:12  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click  button_label_text             Exit Shop
4  2021-01-03 15:13:13  dhj13h     181d9k       exit_app                NaN                   NaN
5  2021-01-03 15:13:15  dhj13h     181d9k  uninstall_app                NaN                   NaN
6  2021-01-04 03:29:01  38nr10     56sf15    install_app       utm_campaign                  null
6  2021-01-04 03:29:01  38nr10     56sf15    install_app         utm_source                  null
7  2021-01-04 18:15:14  38nr10     56sf15       exit_app                NaN                   NaN
8  2021-01-04 18:16:01  38nr10     56sf15  uninstall_app                NaN                   NaN
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `literal_eval` from `ast` over the standard `eval` call?

Comment: @ColdFish `eval` is not considered safe. especially running on output from the outside (internet). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) for example

Answer (score 3):

A version based on [Andrej Kesely's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73641899/15330539) great solution with speed improvements. The differences are:

- I compared the computational time for a bigger input df (`pd.concat([a_df]*1000)`) and found **this
  solution to be way faster as Andrej Kesely's solution, ~50ms vs. 6s**. See below at *Speed testing*.
- Instead of `eval` you can also parse the json column with the `json`-package.
- For readability and debugging, I prefer to not pack everything in one line and avoid `lambda's`, but thats a personal preference of course.

##### Define the unpacker

```py
import json

def read_json(string):
    return [{'event_key': i, 'event_value': j} for i, j in json.loads(string).items()]
    
def explode_json(df, json_column):
    df = df.copy()  # needed to keep df untouched
    
    # read json + json.loads needs " only
    df[json_column] = df[json_column].str.replace("\'", '\"')
    df[json_column] = df[json_column].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x).items())
    
    # explode df, with ignore_index to get unique indexes
    df = df.explode(json_column, ignore_index=True)
    
    df_event = pd.DataFrame(data=df[json_column].to_list(),
                            columns=('event_key', 'event_value'))
    return pd.concat([df.drop(json_column, axis=1), df_event],
                     axis=1, ignore_index=False)
```

##### Apply it

```py
a_df = explode_json(a_df, "event_params")
```

With output (similar to Andrej Kesely):

```
             date_time user_id account_id     event_name          event_key           event_value 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
0  2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click          button_id           shop_screen   
1  2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click   button_container           main_screen   
2  2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click  button_label_text            Enter Shop     
...
```

### Speed testing

Define the function `explode_json_ak` of Andrej Kesely's version. `df.copy()` is needed here to keep the original dataframe across the runs of *timeit*.

```py
def explode_json_ak(df, json_column, inplace=False):
    a_df = df.copy()  # needed to keep df untouched
    a_df = a_df.assign(
        event_params=a_df[json_column].apply(
            lambda x: [{"key": k, "value": v} for k, v in literal_eval(x).items()]
        )
    ).explode(json_column)

    return pd.concat(
        [a_df, a_df.pop(json_column).apply(pd.Series)],
        axis=1,
    ).drop(columns=0)
```

And get both execution times.

```py
df_test = pd.concat([a_df]*1000) # get a bit more data

%timeit -n 2 -r 1 explode_json_ak(df_test, "event_params")  # Andrej Kesely
# 6.51 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 2 loops each)

%timeit -n 3 -r 3 explode_json(df_test, "event_params")  # This solution
# 42 ms ± 1.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 3 loops each)
```

The more events or long the json are, the more difference will be between both versions. The speed gain comes from reading the rows as a DataFrame with avoiding the `.apply()` and `json.loads` is ~4 times faster here than `ast.literal_eval`.

### Different views for the DataFrame

With that exploded format, pandas allows several ways to view it.

- You can change the format of the table like [Josh Friedlander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73679702/15330539) suggested:

```py
a_df.pivot(index=['user_id', 'date_time'], columns='event_key')
```

- or split things into groups

```py
gb = df.groupby(['user_id', 'date_time'])
print(list(gb.groups))  # list of groups: [('38nr10', '2021-01-04 03:29:01'), ...]
gb.get_group(('38nr10', '2021-01-04 03:29:01'))
```

- and more...

Comment: OP's data has single quotes, not double quotes; that'd be against the JSON spec (but not Python's dict literals, which is why `ast.literal_eval` works.)

Comment: (And blindly replacing all single quotes with double quotes will also do so within actual data such as strings.)

Comment: Its also a question of speed. `json.loads` is ~4 times faster than `ast.literal_eval` for the example below. (5.81 µs vs. 21.3 µs).

`a = '{\'button_id\': \'shop_screen\', \'button_container\': \'main_screen\', \'button_label_text\': \'Enter Shop\'}'` -
`%timeit -n 3 -r 3 literal_eval(a)` -
`%timeit -n 3 -r 3 json.loads(a.replace("'", '"'))`

Answer (score 2):

I did some research on EDA on nonrelational data, and there didn't find recommendations that didn't involve wrangling it into a table. (Of course it depends on the type of analysis you want to do - sometimes just visualising nested JSON well can be enough to come up with some ideas.)

Andrej Kesely's answer is great, but I thought it might be helpful to change the data into "wide" format instead of "long", since the keys here can be seen as features of the user action.

```
from ast import literal_eval

a_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

tmp1 =  a_df["event_params"].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x).items()).explode()

tmp2 = pd.DataFrame(tmp1.to_list())
tmp2.index = tmp1.index

a_df = (a_df
        .merge(tmp2
               .dropna(subset=0)
               .pivot(columns=0, values=1), 
               how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
        .drop(columns='event_params'))
```

This gives you a dataframe in which each key is a feature. Then if you want to look at a specific user, you can ignore the irrelevant columns like this:

```
(a_df
.groupby(['user_id', 'account_id'])
.get_group(('38nr10', '56sf15'))
.dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
```

Output:

```
    date_time              user_id  account_id      event_name  utm_campaign    utm_source
6   2021-01-04 03:29:01     38nr10      56sf15      install_app     null    null
7   2021-01-04 18:15:14     38nr10      56sf15      exit_app        NaN     NaN
8   2021-01-04 18:16:01     38nr10      56sf15      uninstall_app   NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative approach without `expload()`

Alternative approach using `pd.json_normalize` and `pd.melt` could also be used to transform the event_params into relational format

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = a_df.merge(
    pd.melt(
        pd.json_normalize(a_df['event_params'].map(lambda x: literal_eval(x))),
        ignore_index=False),
    how='outer',
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True) \
    .drop(columns='event_params')

print(df)
```

output:

```
              date_time user_id account_id     event_name           variable  \
0   2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click          button_id   
0   2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click   button_container   
0   2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click  button_label_text   
0   2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click          screen_id   
0   2021-01-03 15:12:42  dhj13h     181d9k   button_click  screen_controller   
..                  ...     ...        ...            ...                ...   
8   2021-01-04 18:16:01  38nr10     56sf15  uninstall_app          screen_id   
8   2021-01-04 18:16:01  38nr10     56sf15  uninstall_app  screen_controller   
8   2021-01-04 18:16:01  38nr10     56sf15  uninstall_app       screen_title   
8   2021-01-04 18:16:01  38nr10     56sf15  uninstall_app       utm_campaign   
8   2021-01-04 18:16:01  38nr10     56sf15  uninstall_app         utm_source   

          value  
0   shop_screen  
0   main_screen  
0    Enter Shop  
0           NaN  
0           NaN  
..          ...  
8           NaN  
8           NaN  
8           NaN  
8           NaN  
8           NaN  

[72 rows x 6 columns]
```

This would assign `NaN` to events to all actions not related to a particular event, which could be used while analysis